# Fill dynamic array with the rows of visible cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error of "Subscript out of Range" when I'm trying to add the row value, of visible cells (minus the header) to the array. Below the code:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim i as Long
Dim arr() As Long

        Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        i = 0
        For Each r In Rng.Rows
            'Debug.Print r.Row
            arr(i) = r.Row
            i = i + 1
        Next
```

Am I forgetting something ?! I'm still new to VBA and more so, to arrays.

Comment: You have to initialize array. Without it, referencing any element will give this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function works fine...

[image: Input Sheet]

[image: Output from this code]

I didn't get how you are calculating the range... but this output is coming out of the range only.. array is totally dynamic

```
Sub foo()


Dim Rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim arr() As Variant

        Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        i = 1
        For Each r In Rng.Rows
            ReDim Preserve arr(i)
            arr(i) = r.Row
            Debug.Print arr(i)
            i = i + 1
        Next



End Sub
```

Comment: Yup, it works fine with the `ReDim Preserve arr(i)` inside the `For ... Next`. Thank you! And to answer your question on how am I calculating the range, I am taking the `UsedRange` and I am resizing it on the visible cell (`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`). I found this bit of code on a different post on the internet regarding the selection of visible cells.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that although you are declaring the array, you haven't initialised it with a size, so there are no elements in the array hence the subscript out of range.

Your code should read, note the other problem you will have is how you are trying to address the range, I have corrected below:

```
    Dim Rng As Range, r As Range
    Dim i as integer
    Dim ary() as Long

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Redim ary(Rng.Rows.Count)
    i = 0
    For Each r In Rng.Rows
        'Debug.Print r.Row
        arr(i) = CLng(r.Row)
        i = i + 1
    Next
```

This is a tested and working example

Comment: I've tried using `Dim arr(Rng.Rows) as Long`, but I get another error : "Constant expresion required"

Comment: Repost your code, with the new addition, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, you have to define the array. You can give it a fixed size when defining it (`Dim arr(2) as Integer`).

Dynamic ranges can be made with using [`ReDim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement). With `Preserve` it saves the values in the array when redefining the size. (Note: You can only `ReDim` the last dimension of an array)

Comment: I've tried using `ReDim` as `ReDim arr(1 To (ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count / ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns.Count - 1))` but I receive the same error.

Comment: Your index `i` starts at `0`, the array is defined from `1 to ...`